# Half-integer Bessel function evaluated at one

Tags: bessel-functions

Let $K_\alpha$ denote the modified Bessel function of the second kind and order $\alpha$.
We have

$$
K_{1/2}(1) = 2e\sqrt{\pi /2},\\
K_{3/2}(1) = 7e\sqrt{\pi /2},\\
K_{5/2}(1) = 37e\sqrt{\pi /2},\\
K_{7/2}(1) = 266e\sqrt{\pi /2},\\
\text{etc.}
$$

It seems like we always get an integer multiple of $e\sqrt{\pi /2}$.
Does there exist a closed-form or otherwise interesting expression for the integer prefactor? How about other types of Bessel functions?

Comment: See [OEIS A$001515$](http://oeis.org/A001515) and [OEIS A$144301$](http://oeis.org/A144301).